# 400 bad request when using Linkedin api

Tags: c#, .net, linkedin-api, http-status-code-400

From [LinkedIn developer forum thread](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230) I downloaded this sample: LinkedInAuth.rar.zip, it works.

When I use:

```
string response = _oauth.APIWebRequest(
    "GET",
    "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,counts-by-category))?membership-state=member",
     null);
```

It returns all groups.

But when I use:

```
string response = _oauth.APIWebRequest(
    "GET",
    "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{2139884}/posts:(creation-timestamp,title,summary,creator:(first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline),likes,attachment:(image-url,content-domain,content-url,title,summary),relation-to-viewer)?category=discussion&order=recency&modified-since=1302727083000&count=5",
    null);`
```

It returns the error:

> 400 bad request

I used a groups id hard-coded which exist and return by 1st. I tried to follow the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api). Anyone face this problem before or I am missing something.

Comment: @abatishchev Sorry its a type mistake. I edit the Question.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the curly braces around the ID.  The curly braces indicate that you're going to put a variable there.  Try:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{2139884}/posts:(creation-timestamp,title,summary,creator:(first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline),likes,attachment:(image-url,content-domain,content-url,title,summary),relation-to-viewer)?category=discussion&order=recency&modified-since=1302727083000&count=5
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But before 2 days when I post this Question application run perfectly but today when I try to get `oAuth Request Token` and `oAuth Request TokenSecret` its give a `400 bad request`.I am surprise before 2 days its work.Is there any issue of expire developers `API Key` and `Secret Key`?Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your server time. I experienced the same the issue before I changed it (the issue started to happen after the summer time change).